Multi-page dash app with shared data that is generated at start
I have a multi-page dash app with following files:
main.py
import atexit

from dash import Dash
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

from dashboard import layout
from dashboard import dashboard_data


def main():

    app = Dash(assets_folder='dashboard/styles',
               pages_folder='dashboard/pages')

    app.layout = layout.render()    

    app.run(debug=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    _ = dashboard_data.generate_data()
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(func=dashboard_data.generate_data, trigger="interval", minutes=15)
    scheduler.start()
    atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())

    main()

layout.py
import dash
from dash import html
from dash import dcc

def render() -> html.Div:

    layout = html.Div([dash.page_container])

    return layout

dashboard_data.py
data = None

def generate_data() -> dict:
    global data
    data = ...    # expensive calculation
    print('data refreshed')


def get_data() -> dict:
    global data
    return data

page.py
import dash
from dash import html

dash.register_page(__name__)

def layout():
    data = dashboard_data.get_data()
    layout = html.Div(
        children = [...]
    )

In the above I already initialize the data in main.py. There is also a job that should refresh the data every 15 minutes. The page.py then retrieves the data. Running this with app.run(debug=True) often correctly shows the dashboard. I can see that when I run main.py the data is calculated and when I visit the page it is refreshed once at that moment, even though I would not expect this.
If I run as app.run(debug=False) then then this refresh does not happen. The graphs and everywhere else that I show the data in the dashboard then display as empty.
My guess is that this has something to do with the rendering of the layout not waiting on the calculation of the data. I can see from some print statements that the data is still being calculated at the moment that the empty dashboard is displayed. However, refreshing after full calculation does not resolve this.
